# proper way to compare 2-precision floating point with a 4-precision Decimal

Tags: python

I'm running into an interesting problem related to comparing a float against a Decimal:

```
>>> Decimal('1000.1000') == Decimal('1000.10')
True
```

BUT

```
>>> Decimal('1000.1000') == Decimal(1000.10)
False
```

The 2-precision float is coming to me from a 3rd party, so I can't set its precision manually. Is the solution here to convert from float -> str -> Decimal like so?

```
Decimal('1000.1000') == Decimal(str(1000.10))
```

This is janky. Is there a canonical way to do this kind of comparison?

Comment: Well, fundamentally `Decimal('1000.1000')` does not equal `Decimal(1000.10)`... so I think your janky way is pretty much what you want.

Comment: `Decimal('1000.10') != Decimal(1000.10)`; you've already lost the precision in the creation of the float (which isn't *"2-precision"*, see `format(1000.1, '.40f')`). Be explicit, if that is what you want: `Decimal(format(1000.1, '.2f')) == Decimal('1000.1000')`.

Comment: yeah, if by "precision" you mean how many digits you can safely represent, then for "double-precision floating points" that's 15. `Decimal` objects default to something like 30 IIRC, but that is can be arbitrary (one of the selling points of `Decimal` objects).

Comment: @jonrsharpe as i stated in my response, the float is coming from a 3rd party. i could not "be explicit" about it.

Comment: What precisely do you mean *"coming from a 3rd party"*? If they are calling your function with a float, again, *that precision is already lost*. If this is important, perhaps the API should require they pass a Decimal to start with?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Saying "that's 15" is very misleading. It's going to have errors that conversion to `Decimal` is revealing here; the precision of a floating point number is in binary, not decimal, there are a whole host of numbers with very little in the way of decimal digits that it cannot represent accurately,even if it's willing to pretend it have 15 places of precision.

Comment: @ShadowRanger you are correct, of course, that the underlying binary representation causes certain real numbers to be unrepresentable precisely, in the same way `1/3` cannot be represented in decimal precisely. But, the "precision" I was talking about is a well-defined concept, essentially, `floor(log10(2**53))` for double-floating point numbers (IEEE standard). So, as you state, the *precision* isn't the issue here, which is what I was hinting at.

Answer (score 0):

`1000.10` already loses the precision. There's no way to get it back at all. If you already know how precise you'll need it, you can `str` it and then just truncate/round it.

If it's possible, try to keep it as a string or `Decimal` object the entire time, because as soon as it becomes a float, you've already lost precision.